# How complex COBOL programs would fit in 256k?

Tags: history, cobol

This is in reference to [Stack Overflow Podcast #65](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/podcast-65/).  Assume a typical 60's or 70's server computer with, say, 256k main memory.  How large (compiled) COBOL programs could such a machine run at maximum?  How severely would this limit the complexity and capabilities of COBOL programs, assuming that the programs are not deliberately made more complex than necessary?

Comment: Is this a "what's heavier - a ton of bricks or a ton of feathers" question? The size would be somewhat close to 256k ... I don't get it???

Comment: The idea is to get an understanding of how complex programs a mainframe could run.  In the podcast, someone said (I think it was Joel) that since the machines in those days had so little RAM and disk, they wouldn't really be able to run very complex programs.

Comment: CPU speed was much more of a limiting factor. You have 24 hours in a day. However it is split between "batch" and "online", "whatever" still has to fit in 24 hours. No way around that. Ways around size and complexity. Thinking. A simple program is much better than a complex program. If a program can be simplified, then more work can be done, more programs run. A "complex" program was/is a bad thing. A "complex" business requirement is something to be done  in the simplest way (and for each task "simplest" may mean different things).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IBM mainframe operating systems supported virtual storage back then - although you could buy a condo on the beach today for what the yearly IBM lease was!  I don't remember any insurmountable program size issues.

One thing to consider is that back then almost everything was run in "batch programming" mode.  This limited how complex any one program needed to be.  One program would pre-process the data and store it on disk.  The next might sort it and add some calculated result.  Then next might update a database.  Then the last one in the batch might print out a report.  So complexity (and size) was broken up over several programs running in sequence.

Comment: IBM does (and did, going back in the 1980s) support interactive programming on mainframes via their VM/CMS operating systems. This OS combo also supported one of the best scripting languages ever invented - REXX.

Comment: Not only VM/CMS were "interaactive" and none were "interactive" in  terms probably recognised  by "mini-computers" or "PCs".

Answer (score 5):

Fairly large cobol programs can run in 256K ram in a 70's mainframe. (256K of memory in an IBM 370 was 256K 32-bit words, not bytes.) IBM introduced Virtual Memory around 1970. This paged the program and data to disk, allowing a program to use most of the 24-bit address space, with limitations. Just like Windows!

Answer (score 2):

How would you like to measure this? I remember one program that I'm pretty sure we ran in a 256k or 512k system that was about two inches thick when printed out. We didn't have to use overlays, either.

Comment: Measuring the size of programs in a meaningful way is tricky. Maybe average bytes of machine code per line of COBOL code? A semi-useless metric maybe, but better than nothing.

Comment: @Ville: it would be a totally useless metric, since it was never kept. I have no idea what values of that metric we would have had.

Comment: I should mention that this was on DECsystem-10 and DECsystem-20 machines, so 256k would have been 256k 36-bit words.

Answer (score 2):

I was an administrator of a Unisys System 1100 that had 1MB of main storage. We supported about 150 users of a fairly complex munitions inventory system. The application was written COBOL.

Answer (score 0):

If the cobol compiler supports it developers can use SEGMENT in this type of situation and have a kind of load and replace or sometimes overlay is permitted.